# How to emulate a virtual File object using an OutputStream for passing to CSVWRITE?

Tags: java, h2

I have an `OutputStream` to which I want to write some data. It is actually a `CipherOutputStream`. I want to export H2 tables using `CSVWRITE` to the stream.

However the `CSVWRITE` only takes a file name (i.e., `String`). So I want to emulate a virtual File object that is opened using a URI like `memoryFile://foo`, that actually writes to the `OutputStream`, which I can pass to `CSVWRITE` as a URI. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also the possibility to use a Writer

```
ResultSet rs = ...
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
val csv = new Csv();
int row = csv.write(writer, rs);
```

Comment: I think you meant `Csv` (with capital).

Comment: @Jus12 thanks, corrected. If you still do not use compression one could use `new GZipOutputStream(outputStream)?  and `GZipInputStream`.

Comment: Actually both were incorrect. Edited your post to make it correct. +1 for the suggestion of `GZipOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Not in a pure Java way, no.

If you're on a *NIX system, you could create a named pipe and write the output there. Then you can have a program that reads from the pipe, encrypts and writes to a concrete file.